# double foreach loop doesnt loop in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp3.2  php>5 i cant get a double foreach loop to work properly. I treied this simple test to prove what is happening. $lesson is a multidimensional array but I just focus on 1 value  it contains. It just goes through 1 iteration only.
I have a array  with 3 values as you can see. This double foreach loop should produce 3X3 outputs but it just produces 4?
Why is the double foreach loop not looping properly ?

```
its a multi-dimensional array  and i am just using id fields. I want to remove duplicate names using a double foreach

lesson[1][id]='40650'
lesson[1][name]='fred'
lesson[1][name2]='smith'
lesson[2][id]='40651'
lesson[2][name]='fred'
lesson[2][name2]='smith'  
lesson[3][name]='40650'
lesson[3][id]='fred2'
lesson[3][name2]='smith'

  foreach ($lesson as $key1 =>$item){

             debug( $item['id']);

                foreach ($lesson as $key2 =>$item2){

                   debug( $item2['id']);


                }

           }

 \src\Controller\LessonsController.php (line 6429)

(int) 40650

\src\Controller\LessonsController.php (line 6433)

(int) 40650

\src\Controller\LessonsController.php (line 6433)

(int) 40651

\src\Controller\LessonsController.php (line 6433)

(int) 40652
```

Comment: share your array, how it's looking like ?

Comment: ok added it in the OP

Comment: Use group by or distinct in your query to avoid duplicate.

Comment: I've tried your code on PHP 5.6 and 7.3, and it works fine. Is this really all there is, or have you extracted this from some larger piece of code and not fully tested the minimal case?

Comment: There are other nested fields/records which had no nearing on the issue but it must eg lesson[1][student_record][1]='1'

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop goes through the same array `$lesson`

You need to change it to going through the result of the first loop

```
foreach ($lesson as $key1 =>$item) {
   foreach ($item as $key2 => $item2) {
      // Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: no i need to go through the array2 times to compare duplicates.

Comment: @atown99 that is not what you are asking in your question.. what exactly do you want to compare?